# How can I unpack a pydantic BaseModel to make a 'from_config' class method?

Tags: python, class-method, pydantic

I have a class where I want to add a `from_config` class method to use a Pydantic BaseModel

an example would be

```
class Config(BaseModel):
    name: str = "Tom"
    id: int = 1

class User:

    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
         return cls(name=config.name, id=config.id)
```

How can I change this so that the from_config uses unpacking to create the class? for instance, something like

```
    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
         return cls(*config)
```

This isn't working because it is unpacking a tuple from the config basemodel

EDIT:

This works:

```
class Config(BaseModel):
    name: str = "Tom"
    id: int = 1

class User:

    def __init__(self, *, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
         return cls(**config.dict())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user could just be a pydantic model

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33648786)